# Openstack: How to find out VM's key fingerprint before first SSH session

Tags: ssh, openstack, fingerprint, ecdsa, known-hosts

When connecting to a new virtual machine (VM) over SSH for the first time, it is normal to get a message like this:

```
The authenticity of host '▮▮▮.▮▮▮.▮▮▮.▮▮▮ (▮▮▮.▮▮▮.▮▮▮.▮▮▮)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xXxNzzW4OtIxa+O4IDjnj0MmZlrNxHyZtYKw/7rOSfQ.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

If I want to be super-careful, how do I check if the fingerprint matches my VM in OpenStack? I can use the Horizon GUI or the `openstack` CLI, but I can only log into the actual VM with SSH keys, so there's no logging in on the interactive console.

Comment: I guess you could try a cloud-init phone-home module (https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#phone-home) to receive host keys for spawned instances.

Comment: Indeed this is a viable approach if you have time to prepare. Less so if you are a newcomer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the VM is using cloud-init, the host keys should be available on the instance "Log" tab on the Horizon Web interface as a part of the console log / booting process output. The printing helper `write-ssh-key-fingerprints` should run i the cloud-inits final stage.